# Page View + Hidden Navigation Bar doesn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

When I include a Page View as [written by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) in a Navigation View with a hidden Navigation Bar Title, swiping the page makes the title appear.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      PageView(pages: [Text("Foo"), Text("Bar")])
      .navigationBarTitle("Title")
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding a state variable that sets the `navigationBarHidden` Bool to `true` using a button, to no avail. It seems like the connection between the `navigationBarHidden` property and the UI breaks when the Page View flips the page.

I was able to hack something that worked by forcing the view with the navigation title to redraw by putting in both in the `if navigationBarHidden` and `else` blocks and triggering a `.onAppear { isNavigationBarHidden = true }` in the `else` block, but that stinks.

[image: Appearing Title]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I landed on a the hacky solution of including the Page View in a List (which is what Apple did in its [example app](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/7cb0aaabd187acaaca22e41f7fd9bfbc/10200/InterfacingWithUIKit.zip), which is how I found it).

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        PageView(pages: [Text("Foo"), Text("Bar")])
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Title")
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
  }
}
```

I tried including the Page View in a VStack, an AnyView, its own custom View object, none of those worked. I guess it works because a List is inherently Dynamic and so it triggers a whole-view redraw? But it still looks like an Apple bug to me.

I'll still have to massage the UI quite a bit since I actually don't want a List, but it's the best I could find.

[image: Navigation Bar stays hidden]

Comment: did you manage to find something less hacky? Or are you aware of another solution? I have the exact same problem currently. Thanks

Comment: I haven't found another solution.